# My UK visa was refused under deception; is my dependent affected by the same ban?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, ghanaian-citizens

I am a Ghanaian national. My UK visa was refused under deception, meaning I am under automatic ban for next 10 years. Is my dependent affected by the same ban?

Comment: Does your dependent already have a UK visa or reside in the UK?

Comment: Is your dependent a minor?  (I don't know if this is a significant factor, but it seems like it ought to be; it's one thing to ban a dependent 30-year-old spouse for deception since adults are ultimately responsible for their own applications, but it's quite another to ban a dependent child who isn't.)

Comment: Did you make a visa application for your dependent in the same application where you made yours?

Comment: It depends. For children: if you did the application, they are not liable, so when they could do legally sign own application, ban should not be in force. Who sign is the responsible person of the application. In any case, all may have a red flag, and so all dependents must deliver much better proof they will leave UK on time (which may not be easy)

Comment: IANAL, and I can’t find an official source (hence not posting an answer), however I think that anyone applying as a dependent would be ineligible (but not banned) for a dependent visa if the main applicant’s visa was refused. A minor would not be prevented from applying for a different visa if they met the eligibility criteria in their own right. It would help you get an answer if you provided more information eg type of visa you applied for, age of the dependent, and nature of their relationship to you